# Admin Panel is not showing content, Media, Settings

Tags: asp.net, web, content-management-system, firebug, umbraco

I have a problem with Umbraco Admin Panel of my WebSite.

After formatting PC when itried to run WebSite on local IIS Express WebSite lunched correctly but when I tried to go Admin Panel it is doesn't show anything in menu. Below please find screenshot:

http://our.umbraco.org/media/upload/a1af4bbf-1ce8-4370-bcba-7f1f7ac22faf/Screenshot%20(21).png

When I tried to debug Umbraco Admin Panel using FireBug, in Console tab it returns following error:

http://our.umbraco.org/media/upload/bc0a5d4b-573e-457c-86ce-74d83bf87fb3/Untitled.png

Anybody can help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

do you see errors in /App_Data/Logs?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, however I was having the same issue. And for me clearing the cookie fixed it. Hope this might help someone else as well.